# TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, npm-install

I try to start up my web app by 'ng serve', I get this error. Can't figure out why.

I am not really sure what the error is even telling me. I have tried to update all dependencies. I have looked at almost all the similar question solutions and they have not worked. I can't tell if it is a compiler error, typescript, or a dependency error.

> [error] TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
> at setPrototypeOf ()
> at Object.__extends (C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:68:9)
> at C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:118:17
> at C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:325:6
> at C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:3:17
> at Object. (C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:9:3)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
> at C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:21:22
> at C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:10:17
> at Object. (C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:16:3)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)

My package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "Client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.3",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.2.0",
    "acorn": "^6.4.1",
    "agm-direction": "^0.7.9",
    "angular-fusioncharts": "^3.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "events": "^3.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.10.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.1.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.118",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you write what node version you are using ?

Comment: My node version v12.18.2

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that the different angular package major  versions will work together properly. Try updating all angular packages to a same major version. In WebStorm you use the syntax highlighting to gather the latest versions.

And try following in your project folder:

ng update

This will show you what to update exactly.

Answer (score 0):

first, check any node modules outdated by using the following command in your project folder,

```
npm outdated
```

The outdated command will list any packages that are not up to date

is there any outdated then upgrade these by using the command,

```
npm update --save/--save-dev
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you about your answer, I did it and now I get another error: 'An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.' Do you know what I should do for solve it?

Comment: then try to re-install npm by using npm install -g npm-reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Please update the rest of the dependencies. For example typescript is quite outdated. Try upgrading packages like "rxjs": "6.6.0", "typescript": "^3.9.6" etc.